# Как с помощью команды nslookup вывести список всех DNS серверов (серверов имен) корневого домена Интернета , который обозначается точкой

Tags: windows, сервер, ip, dns

Как с помощью команды nslookup вывести список всех DNS серверов (серверов имен) корневого домена Интернета , который обозначается точкой.

Answer (score 1):

```
nslookup -q=NS .
```

или запустив в командном режиме на его приглашение ввести

```
set q=NS
.
```